# Powershell redirect Get-Service to stderr when conection fails

Tags: powershell, stderr, io-redirection

After:

```
$services = Get-Service -ComputerName $server 2>$null
```

The stderr isn't redirected to $null and the error message is printed when conection fails or not enought permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`try`/`catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) to capture (and suppress) the exception:

```
try {
    $services = Get-Service -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop
    # do stuff with $services here
}
catch [InvalidOperationException] {
    # we'll ignore these
}
```